# Getting layer style "name" L.control.layers on map click?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am adding map styles in L.control.layers like this:

```
L.control.layers({
        'Mapbox Light': L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.light',{name:"base"}),
        'S_S': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/geotrek/s***',{name:"F1"}).addTo(map),
        'S_F': L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/f****',{name:"F2"})
    }, null).addTo(map);
```

I can get the layer name on change

```
 map.on('baselayerchange', function(l){
        console.log("baselayerchange",l);
        console.log("baselayerchange",l.layer.options);
        console.log("CONTROLS:", controls)
    })
```

How can I get the current layer style name like S_F or S_S or Mapbox Light or options name on map CLICK event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Leaflet.ActiveLayers](https://github.com/vogdb/Leaflet.ActiveLayers) plugin to achieve that.